# working on dbt want to give the details of snowflake in project.yml file but getting error

Tags: sql, dbt

Trying the give the details of snowfalke in dbt profiles.yml file . but as soon as when ran the command i,e
$atom /home/myname/.dbt/profiles.yml gives below error:
/usr/bin/atom: line 190:  1705 Trace/breakpoint trap   (core dumped) nohup "$ATOM_PATH" --executed-from="$(pwd)" --pid=$$ "$@" > "$ATOM_HOME/nohup.out" 2>&1
Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Permission denied

Following things i tried: Ran below commands but still no luck:
1)
$google-chrome --no-gpu --no-sandbox --disable-setuid-sandbox --headless --dump-dom http://www.chromestatus.com
Error:
[0627/161930.251811:ERROR:udev_watcher.cc(61)] Failed to enable receiving udev events.
[0627/161932.565713:ERROR:platform_shared_memory_region_posix.cc(46)] Descriptor access mode (0) differs from expected (2)
[0627/161932.566251:WARNING:crash_handler_host_linux.cc(366)] Could not translate tid - assuming crashing thread is thread group leader; syscall_supported=0
[0627/161932.769040:WARNING:crash_handler_host_linux.cc(366)] Could not translate tid - assuming crashing thread is thread group leader; syscall_supported=0
--2020-06-27 16:19:32--  https://clients2.google.com/cr/report
Resolving clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)... 2404:6800:4009:805::200e, 172.217.174.238
Connecting to clients2.google.com (clients2.google.com)|2404:6800:4009:805::200e|:443... [0627/161933.036124:ERROR:headless_shell.cc(399)] Abnormal renderer termination.
connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/plain]
Saving to: ‘/dev/fd/4’
0K
Crash dump id:    e870824b56e91b9f

2. $ google-chrome
   Error:
   Failed to move to new namespace: PID namespaces supported, Network namespace supported, but failed: errno = Permission denied
   Trace/breakpoint trap (core dumped)
   [1772:1772:0100/000000.825375:ERROR:zygote_linux.cc(653)] write: Broken pipe (32)
   [0627/162152.831614:ERROR:nacl_helper_linux.cc(308)] NaCl helper process running without a sandbox!
   Most likely you need to configure your SUID sandbox correctly

Could any one advise on the above issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be an atom error. Could be packages or something that they installed. I could be wrong, but I don’t see anything in that error message that indicates it’s a profiles.yml thing. I wonder if they can open other files in atom just fine?
Alternatively, use a text editor that isn’t based on chrome
Thanks @jake and @Christine from FishTown Analytics.

Here are a few helpful links.
[Atom issue](https://github.com/atom/atom/issues/3056);
[Blogpost](https://equk.co.uk/2018/04/02/forcing-namespace-sandbox-in-chrome-electron)!

Comment: Thanks for response .  But found  below link which solves the issue.https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/automatically-configuring-wsl/